# Menu item IDs in an Android library project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

The Android app uses a library project to contain most of the app code, as there are two versions of the app built from the core source. Since an IntelliJ IDEA update (to v11) I'm getting this warning on each of the case statements below:

```
Resource IDs cannot be used in a switch statement in Android library modules
```

Here's the code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_one:   // Build error here
            // Do stuff
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_two:   // Build error here
            // Do stuff
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

OK, so if I can't reference them via their ID, how DO I reference them?

Comment: I suppose one solution would be to dynamically create the menu items, but that removes all the benefits of using resources for menus. These errors seem to be saying it's not possible to use XML menu definitions in library projects?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Substitute the `switch` with an `if/else if` construct.

```
int id = item.getItemId();
if(id == R.id.menu_item_one) {
    // ...
}
else if(id == R.id.menu_item_two) {
    // ...
}
```

This is neccessary since ADT 14 because the final modifier was removed from id's in the R class.

*See [Non-constant Fields in Case Labels](http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields)*