# Android library project: calling a method of an inner class

Tags: java, android, scope

I'm in the process of splitting an Android project into a library project + several dependent projects, and ran into this problem.

The library project has an Android `Service` defined like this:

```
public class UserService extends Service {

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        UserService getService() {
            return UserService.this;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The dependent project makes a call to a method of an inner class of the `Service` like this:

```
public ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;            
    }
    ...
};
```

This works fine when everything's in the same project.  But after I moved the Service into the library project, it gives a compile-time error:

```
The method getService() from the type UserService.LocalBinder is not visible
```

What do I need to change to make it compile?

Answer (score 4):

Your method doesn't have any visibility modifier, so it's only visible from classes in the same package. Make it public to make it accessible from any other class:

```
    public UserService getService() {
        return UserService.this;
    }
```

Read [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to learn about visibility modifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I tried that, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: I got the original code to work again.  I had another issue related to library project conversion as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476912/menu-item-ids-in-an-android-library-project.  When I fixed that, this error went away - not sure why/how they are related, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)